# Return value from class that has event: ADDED_TO_STAGE

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cc

I have a class with ADDED_TO_STAGE event (it's an incomplete dialog), and I want it to return a value. Is this possible? Or what's the what's the way I should follow?

My class: http://sudrap.org/paste/text/555684/

**Edit:** I'll create some buttons in the class. I want buttons' functions to return some value. And I'll need to get which button is clicked. I want to pass these values to main fla.

I'll probably need the class to return an array for settings specified in the dialog.

Comment: I don't see you trying to return a value anywhere in your code (except DrawRectangle, but that seems unrelated?). When do you want to return it? When you create the Object of your class? Please, rephrase your question to make it clearer. There is also no reason to put your code off-site.

Comment: Want to return a value or passing some parameters? What is the type you want to return and for what?

Comment: thanks for the answers. I edited the question. I didn't paste the code to this question because this site didn't allow it because of excessive code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by creating your custom event class that extends `Event` and pass your required parameters within.

```
    package{
    import flash.events.Event;
    public class CustomEvent extends Event{

        public static const PASS_PARAMS:String = "passParams";

        // Your custom properties.
        public var btnName:*;

        public function CustomEvent(type:String, bName:*, bubbles:Boolean=false, cancelable:Boolean=false):void {
            this.btnName = bName;
            super(type, bubbles, cancelable);
        }

        override public function clone():Event{
            return new CustomEvent(type,btnName, bubbles, cancelable);
        }
     }
   }
```

and dispatch your `customEvent` on button click event whenever happens

```
    btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onBtnClick);
    private function onBtnClick(e:MouseEvent):void{
        dispatchEvent(new Event(CustomEvent.PASS_PARAMS, e.target.name));
    }
```

and add a listener on your Main class

```
    this.addEventListener(CustomEvent.PASS_PARAMS, onProcessedEvent);       
    private function onProcessedEvent(e:CustomEvent):void{
        trace(e.btnName);
    }
```

Comment: hello, I wasn't sure where to put your second block of code but when I put it to my class in this question, I'm getting error: http://sudrap.org/paste/text/556048/

Comment: I'm confused. I moved your first and second part of code to my class, and third part to my main fla. CustomEvent.as: http://sudrap.org/paste/text/556089/    main fla: http://sudrap.org/paste/text/556092/    now I'm getting error 1061.

Comment: CustomEvent is a Class and it inherits all the properties and methods of the Event class.. keep it as separate.

Comment: wow! I did what you said and changed dispatchEvent(new Event(CustomEvent.PASS_PARAMS, e.target.name)); TO dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(CustomEvent.PASS_PARAMS, e.target.name)); then it worked like a charm. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking what you have there is a **`view`**.
Something visual that the user can interact with.

You should define your `view` in that class. Apparently you want to pass a bunch of comboboxes and checkboxes to your class.
This is **not** the way to do this.

comboboxes and checkboxes are themselves views. They are also called components (because they provide additional functionality like styling, etc).
If your popup should be made up of comboboxes and checkboxes that's fine.
Create them in your class PopupDialog, but do not pass them to the class.

The thing that you should pass to your class is the **`model`**, that is the data that the user should be able to modify.

In the realm of Flash's components, this is a `DataProvider` object.
Take a look at the [description of the `.dataProvider` property of the ComboBox](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/controls/ComboBox.html#dataProvider) class:

> Gets or sets the data model of the list of items to be viewed. A data provider can be shared by multiple list-based components. Changes to the data provider are immediately available to all components that use it as a data source.

As you can see the `model` or `dataProvider` holds some data.
It is an object that is shared by all views that display that very same data.
As soon as this data is manipulated in any way, all other `views` are notified of that change.

I hope you can see how this solves your problem: it doesn't matter if your `view` is a popup or not. As long as it operates on a `model` that is shared with the rest of your application, the functionality to return the value is already there.

Comment: plus one for the detailed answer. thanks a lot. I'll try it and mark this answer as accepted if it works.